# 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed Error insert in session xml value

Tags: xml, serialization, simplexml, php

Hi all I have a site developed in codeigniter.
I'm parsing an xml that I retrieve from a server and I want to put the return value into a session variable.
But return me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed

My PHP version on my vps is:
PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

This is my code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(curl_exec($ch2));
$error2=curl_getinfo( $ch2, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
curl_close($ch2);
foreach ($xml->DATA as $entry){
    $code_travco = $entry->attributes()->COUNTRY_CODE;
    $name_en =  $entry->COUNTRY_NAME;
    $newdata = array(
        'code'  => $code_travco,
        'name_en'     =>  $name_en
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($code_travco.'_nation_en', $newdata);      
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

may be try changing it to string before adding, like:

```
foreach ($xml->DATA as $entry){
    $code_travco = (string) $entry->attributes()->COUNTRY_CODE;
    $name_en =  (string) $entry->COUNTRY_NAME;
    $newdata = array(
        'code'  => $code_travco,
        'name_en'     =>  $name_en
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($code_travco.'_nation_en', $newdata);      
 }
```

Comment: it works great! But why isn't a string? which format is before put (string)?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri its resource type and resources cannot be serialized, hence the error..

Comment: It's not resource type but an object of type `SimpleXMLElement`. Just FYI. And it can not be serialized as the error message says. But it supports casting to string (which resource types to not support that way).

Comment: This was so helpful - what I don't understand is why is this not an error 500 - rather, my Firefox just says page cannot be displayed. I only found this error deep in my error log! #HairPullout